# How to write oneline string in multipe lines?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to send a big json with long string field by curl, how should I crop it to multiple lines? For example:

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:3000/upload' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
  -d "{
    \"markdown\": \"# $TITLE\\n\\nsome content with multiple lines....\\n\\nsome content with multiple lines....\\n\\nsome content with multiple lines....\\n\\nsome content with multiple lines....\\n\\n\"
  }"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool like `jq` to generate your JSON, rather than trying to manually construct it. Build the multiline string in the shell, and let `jq` encode it. Most importantly, this avoids any potential errors that could arise from `TITLE` containing characters that would need to be correctly escaped when forming your JSON value.

```
my_str="# $TITLE
some content with multiple lines...
some content with multiple lines...
some content with multiple lines..."

my_json=$(jq --argjson v "$my_str" '{markdown: $v}')

curl -X POST 'localhost:3000/upload' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d "$my_json"
```

`curl` has the ability to read the data for `-d` from standard input, which means you can pipe the output of `jq` directly to `curl`:

```
jq --argjson v "$my_str" '{markdown: $v}' | curl ... -d@-
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split anything to multiple lines using the technique already in your post, by terminating lines with `\`.
If you need to split in the middle of a quoted string,
terminate the quote and start a new one.
For example these are equivalent:

```
echo "foobar"
echo "foo""bar"
echo "foo"\
     "bar"
```

But for your specific example I recommend a much better way.
Creating the JSON in a double-quoted string is highly error prone,
because of having to escape all the internal double-quotes,
which becomes hard to read and maintain as well.
A better alternative is to use a here-document,
pipe it to `curl`, and use `-d@-` to make it read the JSON from stdin.
Like this:

```
formatJson() {
    cat << EOF
{
  "markdown": "some content with $variable in it"
}
EOF
}

formatJson | curl -X POST 'localhost:3000/upload' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
  -d@-
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd save the JSON to a file:

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:3000/upload' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d "$(cat my_json.json)"
```

Comment: The json data is generated by the shell script it self, rather than load from file.

Comment: Curl can do `-d @my_json.json` for exactly this.

Comment: @kcats If the data is generated by another command, what do you need to split? Your question implies you have a large hard-coded literal.

Comment: @chepner the data's `markdown` field is generated by the variables, it contains some information generated by the script. In other words, I hope to generate a json with a big string field. I could not wrap the string because JSON does not support it.